# convert curl notification command to urllib2 -kaaproject

Tags: curl, urllib2, iot, kaa

I am trying to convert following curl command to send notification via urllib2

```
curl -v -S -u devuser:devuser123 -F'notification={"applicationId":"4","schemaId":"14","topicId":"3","type":"USER"};type=application/json' -F'endpointKeyHash=lsXnYUbE31aCgN5NSsbcRMAZTgM=;type=text/plain' -F file={"message" : "Hello world!"} "http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendUnicastNotification" | python -mjson.tool
```

and i write this code for send notification

```
import urllib2, base64
data = 'notification={"applicationId":"4","schemaId":"14","topicId":"3","type":"USER"};type=application/json&endpointKeyHash=xQXJ7OzFX4M6W5tl4sVTuWLTuzc=;type=text/plain&file={"message":"Hello world!"}'

url="http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendUnicastNotification"

request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
#authentication part
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ('devuser', 'devuser123')).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
the_page = result.read()
```

but when i run this code i encourage the following error

```
line 527, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type
```

problem probably is about send multiple data through urllib2 but how can i send that parameters to kaa server via urllib2?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a content-type header as multipart/form-data for your request. That is why you get the "unsupported media type" error.